# Помогите сделать конфиг Apache из nginx

Tags: php, apache, nginx, apache2

Здравствуйте, есть такой конфиг nginx

```
location /recovery.pb {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /libs/recovery_pass.php;
}
```

и такой скрипт php

```
<?php
require("../init.php");
echo basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
```

Когда иду на `/recovery.pb/token1/` token1 не выводится, причина ниже

Апач обрабатывает php, а nginx работает как фронтенд (отдает статику). Сделать, чтобы Apache менял `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` старого скрипта на новый сделать у меня почему то не получается. Такой .htaccess (лежит в корне):

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On 
     RewriteBase /  

    RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/libs/recovery_pass.php.*
    RewriteRule  ^/$   /recovery.pb  [L]

    </IfModule>
```

Помогите правильно сконфигурировать .htaccess

P.S. Делаю самописный скрипт, и хочется, чтоб восстановление пароля выглядело следующим образом: /recovery.pb/token/

UPD:
Полный конфиг nginx

```
server {
    server_name domain.ru www.domain.ru;
    charset UTF-8;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    index index.html index.php;
    root $root_path;
    set $root_path /var/www/blits/data/www/pb***.ru;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/pb****.ru.access.log ;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/pb***.ru.error.log notice;
    listen 46.36.***.150:80 default_server;
    listen [2a03:****:1:19::22]:80 default_server;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    location / {
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
        }

            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;

    }
    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        access_log off ;
    }
    ssi on;
    error_page 404 /errorpages/404.php;
location /index.pb {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /new.php;
}
location /cabinet.pb {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /cabinet/new.php;
}
location /recovery.pb {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /libs/recovery_pass.php;
}

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }

# тут было gzip сжатие
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В nginx надо не забыть про `proxy_pass`!

```
server {
        listen   80; 

        root /var/www/; 
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name example.com; 

        location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /libs/recovery_pass.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }
}
```

А в apache перекидывайте все запросы к несуществующим URL таким вот .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /libs/recovery_pass.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваше желание помочь. Нет, увы не работает. А куда вы дели /recovery.pb? Видимо вы меня неправильно поняли, нужно перенаправлять с /libs/recovery_pass.php на /recovery.pb. В nginx я это сделал, но обрабатывает то php файлы apache

Comment: Дополнил полным конфигом nginx на всякий случай

Comment: дополнил, толку 0, обновил вопрос